# Apache-CXF JAX-WS client error : Message part not recognized

Tags: java, apache, web-services, soap, wsdl

I wrote a webservice using Apache-CXF. It works fine when tested with SoapUI. I wrote a Java client to call the webservice, and it fails with the following error:

org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Message part customer was not recognized.  (Does it exist in service WSDL?)

The client program reads data from a xml file and adds it as a Document to the SOAPBody.

Here is the input data in SoapUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:app="ApplyLoanRequest">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <app:customer>
         <contact>
            <!--1 to 2 repetitions:-->
            <name part="first">J</name>
            <name part="last">H</name>
            <country>US</country>
         </contact>
      </app:customer>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Here is the SOAP generated by my client available on the console from the writeTo System.out

Starting BankLoan Client ...

Service request ...

====================================

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:app="ApplyLoanRequest"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><customer>

        <contact>
            <!--1 to 2 repetitions:-->
            <name part="first">J</name>
            <name part="last">H</name>
            <country>IN</country>
        </contact>
</customer></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Service response ...

====================================

soap:Fault
faultcode = soap:Client

The difference is that in SoapUI, the root element is sent with namespace, as app:customer whereas in my client program there is no prefix. Is this causing the error? How do I prefix the root element with app: ?

Here is the Java client program:

```
    public class BankLoanClient
    {

        public Document convertXMLFileToDocument(String pathToFile) throws Exception
        {
            DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(pathToFile);

            return doc;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
        {
            System.out.println("Starting BankLoan Client ... ");

            SOAPMessage message = MessageFactory.newInstance().createMessage();
            SOAPBody    body    = message.getSOAPBody();

            SOAPPart     part     = message.getSOAPPart();
            SOAPEnvelope envelope = part.getEnvelope();
            envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("app", "ApplyLoanRequest");

            body.addDocument(new BankLoanClient().convertXMLFileToDocument(args[0]));

            System.out.println("Service request ... ");
            System.out.println("====================================");
            message.writeTo(System.out);
            System.out.println();

            URL endpoint = new URL("http://localhost:8080/bankloan/services/applyloan");
            SOAPConnectionFactory factory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection connection = factory.createConnection();

            SOAPMessage response = connection.call(message, endpoint);
            connection.close();

            // Process the response message
            SOAPBody respBody = response.getSOAPBody();
            Iterator it = respBody.getChildElements();
            SOAPBodyElement element = (SOAPBodyElement) it.next();
            System.out.println("Service response ... ");
            System.out.println("====================================");
            System.out.println(element.getNodeName());

            it = element.getChildElements();
            SOAPElement ret = (SOAPElement) it.next();
            System.out.println(ret.getNodeName() + " = " +  ret.getTextContent());
        }
    }
```

Even if I change the URL to point at the wsdl, I get the same error.

```
URL endpoint = new URL("http://localhost:8080/bankloan/services/applyloan?wsdl");
```

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Comment: No. Checked with half a dozen Java experts, but couldn't resolve it.

Comment: One of my co-workers resolved the problem we were experiencing. It seemed that they had to download the wsdl to a file and then we no longer experienced the issue. We are using a non standard java soap client though.